# How to get session filenames for specific users (php)?

Tags: php, session

I am trying to disconnect specific users only.
For that, I have done :

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/php/sessions`

and

```
$sid = session_id();
$path = '/var/lib/php/sessions/'; // default session path
$sessionfile = $path . "sess_" . $sid;
$files = glob($path.'*'); // get all file names
foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
if(is_file($file) && $file !=$sessionfile) 
unlink($file); // delete file
}
```

which works but disconnects **all** users (but one who has made the request).

I can easily get the id of specific users but how can I get corresponding session filenames ?

```
$sql = "SELECT  `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `user_profile`=?  ";
$param = [$profile_in];
$users = $this->core->fetchAll($sql, $param); 
foreach ($users as $id=>$user) { // I search if user has a specific profile
    $sid = $_SESSION[$user['user_id']]; // get id 
    $sessionfile = $path . "sess_" . $sid; // get corresponding session file 
    unlink($sessionfile);
}
```

The above code does not work as   `$sid = $_SESSION[$user['user_id']];`  returns false.

Best

Comment: "I am trying to disconnect specific users only" - what does that mean? Why not use a database for this? That could help you way better to connect a session ID to a user ID

Comment: This means I want to kill specific sessions

Comment: You have no way, currently, of connecting a user to a specific Session file. Until you can do that you cannot do what you want

Comment: So this means, I have to store the session filename (upon login) in a db ?

Comment: Remember, if your code is doing something like this `$sid = $_SESSION[$user['user_id']];` that is accessing YOUR SESSION not someone elses

Comment: So no way of doing this like that ? And so, I have to store the session file name in a db ?

Comment: You will have to store it somewhere accessible to others (special people only) , a database sounds like a sensible solution